# Variable in Format Function Command

Tags: python, string-formatting

This is a basic use of the format command.

```
test = 23423.3

print("{:>10.2f}".format(test))
```

It'll output "  23423.30".

However, I want to use the format command where the alignment is potentially not always the same.

For example, if I wanted the alignment to be 12 digits instead:

```
test = 23423.3
num = 12
print("{:>num.2f}".format(test))
```

However, this obviously won't work. Is there a way to do this in the format command? If not, what is an alternative?

Comment: For info on nested replacement fields in a `format_spec` field see the second-last paragraph of the [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) docs.